# AudioQueuePrime Fails with -66674

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have some code which does recording/seeking/playback using AudioQueue using either PCM or IMA4.  Now this code is working fine on the simulator but when it's time to use on the iphone playback gives the error -66674 on AudioQueuePrime.  I am mostly curious as to what are possible causes to this error as the documentation leaves much to be desired.

I've linked the relevant documentation below, this is done on iphone-sdk-4.0 and again simulator works fine but the device returns this error.  I've tried to let AudioQueuePrime prepare all frames as well as requesting a single frame.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueuePrime

Answer (score 3):

From the header file here: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioQueue.h`

We see: `kAudioQueueErr_PrimeTimedOut = -66674` which can be found at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html). It says:

> During a call to the AudioQueuePrime function, the audio queue’s audio converter failed to convert the requested number of sample frames.